# Powershell script assign food to numbers and list them

Tags: powershell

The script should allocate and list the numbers of the particular foods.
So i want a Script that makes a "Plan" of the Food i'm gonna eat this week.
i have a counter that can "choose from 200 meals".
So what i need is that it is like this:

number* = Tacos

number* = Pizza

...continuing like this

I don't have a clue how to do this... i hope you can help me!
here is my code untill now.

```
# Food selector for the week!
#random Stuff mixed for every day.
function Random-Food{

Param(
     [array]$InputList
   )

   return $InputList | Get-Random -Count 7 
   $InputList.Count;
}

$a = 1..200
Write-Output (Random-Food -InputList $a)
```

Comment: Are you in any way implying that you would have 200 **different** choices of food (WOW! that surely adds a lot of variety to your food) and among those 200, you will randomly select any 7 for the week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a separate file, create an enumeration (for readability):

```
Enum Food
{
    Tacos
    Pizza
    ...
}
```

In your script, dot-source this file so you have it available: `. 'C:\myenum.ps1'`

Then in your function:

```
function Get-Food {
    [Enum]::GetValues([Food]) | Get-Random -Count 7
}
```

This will return 7 random foods from your list.  As an added bonus, you can assign a number to each food and get that reference as well. (`Tacos = 5` and access it like `[Food]::Tacos` which can be treated as a string or integer)

---

To include the day:

```
function Get-Food {
    $foodsOfWeek = [Enum]::GetValues([Food]) | Get-Random -Count 7

    foreach ($day in [Enum]::GetValues([DayOfWeek])) {
        ([string]$day).Substring(0, 3) + ': ' + $foodsOfWeek[$day]
    }
}
```

An explanation:
The function will grab all the values (Tacos, Pizza, etc.) from your custom `[Food]` enumeration and then randomly select 7 of those to put into an array that we store into `$foodsOfWeek`.

At that point, we need to loop through the days of the week (system built-in enumeration `[DayOfWeek]`).  We type-cast to a string so we can call the `.Substring()` method to grab the first 3 characters and append a `:` for formatting.

Finally, we access the `$foodOfWeek` array using the `[DayOfWeek]` enumeration since days correlate to the numbers 0-6 (the size of our array).

```
(DayOfWeek.Sunday == 0) && (DayOfWeek.Sunday == "Sunday")) == true
```

Comment: @alex In simplest terms, it's a way to import your other script.  If you do not want to do that, you can define the enumeration inside your function/script as an alternative.

Comment: thanks for this solution !
i saw that there is a possibillity to set the weekdays infront of it so it looks a bit better... how would i implement this here? like in the solution below

Comment: @alex Glad to be of service. If this solved your question, kindly mark it as the answer ✅

Comment: of corse :) I did  :D (you'r solution matches my minimalistic view the most and is verry good to add a big list in it! :D)

Answer (score 0):

To learn PowerShell, try this: [Windows PowerShell 3.0 Step by Step - Pearsoncmg.com](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi68KSIppnbAhULOawKHWEdDakQFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com%2Fimages%2F9780735669192%2Fsamplepages%2F9780735669192.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2bfAq-vLw4YvqR2MQN9AKN)

Freebie follows. Written and tested on A Win 7 machine with `PowerShell 4`. I included a few foods. All you have to do is add items to the `$foodList`.

Sample output follows the code

```
cls
#define an array of strings and load it with food words 

$foodList = @("Apples","Bananas", "Cherries","Grapes","Mangoes","Melons","Oranges","Peaches","Pears","Pineapples","Strawberries","Tomatoes")

#define an array of days
$dow = @("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun")

#loop 7 times, once per day and generate a random number between 0 and the number of food items - 1

for ($i = 0; $i -lt 7; $i++)
{ 
    $foodItemIndex = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum ($foodList.Count - 1)
    write-host ($dow[$i] + ": " + $foodList[$foodItemIndex])
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're not using any features that are beyond v2 (the v4 disclaimer and 3.0 is unnecessary here).  I'd suggest learning from 5.1 since Windows 10 is finally here and the times you need to know when features were added are almost gone.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: I'm just letting alex know which machine and version of PS my program was tested on. And, not all of us have access to a Win 10 machine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$foodChoices = "Pizza","Taco","Dim Sum","Burger","Salad","Soup","Sandwich","Curry"

$foodChoices[(Get-Random -InputObject (0..($foodChoices.Count - 1)) -Count 7)] |
    ForEach-Object {$daysOfWeek = [enum]::GetNames([DayOfWeek]); $day=0}{
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Day=$daysOfWeek[$day++]
            Food=$_
        }
    }
```

Output will look something like this:

```
Day       Food    
---       ----    
Sunday    Burger  
Monday    Sandwich
Tuesday   Salad   
Wednesday Taco    
Thursday  Soup    
Friday    Dim Sum 
Saturday  Curry
```

Just add more items to `$foodChoices` and you're good to go ...